# Customising Overleaf Template

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, templates, overleaf

I guys,

I am using [**this**](https://it.overleaf.com/latex/templates/univaq-technical-report-template/fzgkhmygfwvh) technical report template that I consider robust and well built. I tried to change the template adapting it to my needs and I managed almost in everything, except for two kind of customizations.

I am therefore writing hoping that someone can give me an indication on how to make:

1. decrease the vertical space above the titles of each chapter;
2. insert a footer (maybe with Fancyhdr) also in the initial pages of
   the chapters. I can insert it, but only in the second pages. I found
   the portion of code that regulates Header and Footer, but I can't
   customize it.

Does someone know how to solve these two questions?

Thank you,
C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: more specific footer settings, see below.**

The template use the `memoir` document class, which has a lot of customizability. You can make these changes in `preamble/general.tex`:

line 166, change

```
\setlength\beforechapskip{0mm}
```

to

```
\setlength\beforechapskip{-3cm}
```

or whatever fits your design.

Footers: for the first page of a chapter pagestyle `plain` is used, for the others pagestyle `myruled`. You have to change the footers for both.
Line 195-196:

```
\makeevenfoot{myruled}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{myruled}{}{}{}
```

change to

```
\makeevenfoot{myruled}{MY FOOTER}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{myruled}{MY FOOTER}{}{}
```

Line 212-213:

```
\makeevenfoot{plain}{}{}{}            % No page number on plain even pages (chapter begin)
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{}             % No page number on plain odd pages (chapter begin)
```

change to

```
\makeevenfoot{plain}{MY FOOTER}{}{}            % No page number on plain even pages (chapter begin)
\makeoddfoot{plain}{MY FOOTER}{}{}             % No page number on plain odd pages (chapter begin)
```

Change the comments to whatever is appropriate.

**More specific footer settings, as indicated in the comment.**

```
\makeevenhead{myruled}{}{}{\hffont\leftmark} % No page number
\makeoddhead{myruled}{\hffont\rightmark}{}{} % No page number
\makeevenfoot{myruled}{\hffont Lorem ipsum dolor}{\hffont Again lorem ipsum}{\hffont Page \thepage~of \thelastpage}
\makeoddfoot{myruled}{\hffont Lorem ipsum dolor}{\hffont Again lorem ipsum}{\hffont Page \thepage~of \thelastpage}
\renewcommand{\footruleheight}{\normalrulethickness}
...
\makeevenfoot{plain}{\hffont Lorem ipsum dolor}{\hffont Again lorem ipsum}{\hffont Page \thepage~of \thelastpage}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{\hffont Lorem ipsum dolor}{\hffont Again lorem ipsum}{\hffont Page \thepage~of \thelastpage}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @Pietervanoostrum, your answer helped me a lot. I've set the lenght of the chapter's skip and now it's great. Instead, for the footer part, I have still some troubles. What I want to obtain is something like this, in all the pages of the document, except for the first two pages:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nR5Gzvw6s0PFQT7vcyHmcQ6-Op7z-J0a/view?usp=sharing

Do you think it would be possible?

Comment: See the edit in the answer

Comment: Dear @Pietervanoostrum, you solved my question, thank you. What if I want to insert the same horizontal line in the HEADER also?

I tried writing this command, but it doesn't seem to work.

`\renewcommand{\headruleheight}{\normalrulethickness}`

Comment: I suppose you mean on the first page of a chapter, because on all other pages there is already a horizontal line. This would do that: `\makeheadrule{plain}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}`

Comment: Dear @Pietervanoostrum, I meant everywhere **except** for the first page of a chapter, where there is already a horizontal line. So I just changed `plain` with `myruled` in your code and everything worked:  `\makeheadrule{myruled}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}`. Again, thank you very much!